# Word 2010 template table generation

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word, word-2010

I'm trying to use Word 2010 to create a template for a programming project test plan.  I've created a mockup template showing what I want to do.

[image: Project Test Plan Mockup]

What I'd like to be able to do is be able to click on something on the Word ribbon, and have the template generate the next test table and sequence the caption.  Once the table is generated, I would fill in the table fields for the test.

Could someone tell me what to look up in the Word help or elsewhere so I can create this template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would create a macro for this or you can embed it in your template with code to add menu items and add something like the following. (It's very rough but you can use it to generate a table with your layout and numeric ascending numbers), it is not as dynamic as knowing where the previous test left off but should be a start point.)

```
Dim iCount As Integer

iCount = CInt(InputBox("How many tables?", "Table Count", 1))

For icurtable = 1 To iCount

    Dim oTableRange As Paragraph
    Dim oTable As Table
    Dim oCaption As Paragraph

    Set oCaption = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Add

    Call oCaption.Range.InsertBefore(CStr(icurtable))

    Set oTableRange = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Add

    Set oTable = oTableRange.Range.Tables.Add(oTableRange.Range, 4, 1, True, True)

    oTable.Rows.First.Cells(1).Range.InsertBefore ("Setup:")
    oTable.Rows(2).Cells(1).Range.InsertBefore ("Test:")
    oTable.Rows(3).Cells(1).Range.InsertBefore ("Expected Response:")
    oTable.Rows(4).Cells(1).Range.InsertBefore ("Restore")

    Call oTableRange.Range.InsertAfter(vbCrLf)

Next
```

Comment: I took out the for loop.  It's not exactly one click, but I can insert a table where I want.  Thanks for helping me get started.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else comes across this question, I'll provide my solution.  I decided to create a table inside of a table so the test case number will be on the left, where people expect to see it.

Using Sacha's answer as a model, and making liberal use of the macro recorder, I came up with this VBA macro that does most of what I want.

```
Sub InsertTestTable()

'
' InsertTestTable Macro
' This macro inserts a test table into the document.
'

Dim oTable As Table
Dim iTable As Table

Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Selection.Range, 1, 2, _
    wdWord9TableBehavior, wdAutoFitContent)

Selection.TypeText ("1.")
Selection.MoveRight

Set iTable = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Selection.Range, 4, 2, _
    wdWord9TableBehavior, wdAutoFitContent)

iTable.Rows(1).Cells(1).Range.InsertBefore ("Setup:")
iTable.Rows(2).Cells(1).Range.InsertBefore ("Test:")
iTable.Rows(3).Cells(1).Range.InsertBefore ("Expected Response:")
iTable.Rows(4).Cells(1).Range.InsertBefore ("Restore:")

iTable.Rows(1).Cells(2).Range.Select

End Sub
```

Now, all I need to do is format the tables the way I want, and figure out how to have the number ascend through the set of tables in the document.